# Write to CouchDB in the background to improve timing/reliability

Tags: python, performance, couchdb

I have a high-throughput WSGI app that receives many POSTs per second from a remote server and writes documents to a couchdb server. Currently, the writes to couchdb can only happen between request and response. That means

1. if writes to couchdb are slow, then the client must sit waiting for a response while we write to the database, and
2. if there are problems writing to the couchdb server, there is no way to wait a few minutes and retry

Are there any existing solutions to queue up the writes to couch in the background (I'm looking at something like [celery](http://celeryproject.org/), for example), or will I need to roll my own solution?

Comment: Easier to answer if you let us know why your example, celery, isn't a good fit for you?

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson: Good point! Celery may well be a good fit, I only just discovered it and can't tell yet how well it would work for what I want. I asked because I'm wanting to check if there's any sort of "duh" solution to this specific problem, like writing to a small local couchdb instance and replicating it (I've been told that specific idea could be a can of worms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`celery` could do that, yes, or any other task queue of a similar nature.

(Alternatively you could go one step lower and use a any message queue server, plus your own independent worker process that consumes from the message queue.)